# Update values in column across multiple tables using where

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a database that contains data for multiple divisions within a company.  Each division is given a code that allows certain data elements to be exclusive to them.  This code is housed in the 'agency' column.  Not all tables have an agency column, but I do not know which ones do or do not have this column.

One of the divisions has had their agency code changed and this now needs to be be altered within the database across all tables.

How do I script a change that will look across all tables, update 'value1' to 'value1a' in the agency column where agency = 'value1', but only run the update portion when/if the agency column is found to be present?

I've tried several types of scripts, the two most prevalent being either:

- trying to adapt sp_msforeachtable to work, which doesn't seem to accomdodate a where clause
- trying to generate a list of update statements by polling information_schema using a script like this:

  ```
  select 'update dbo.' + t.TABLE_NAME + ' set agency = value1 where agency = value1a'
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
  join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1
  on T.TABLE_NAME = C1.TABLE_NAME
  join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2
  on t.TABLE_NAME = c2.TABLE_NAME
  where t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
  and c1.COLUMN_NAME = 'agency'
  and c2.COLUMN_NAME = 'agency'
  ```

it gives me back a long list of scripts to run individually against each table, but then I get an error trying to run the result set:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'Value1'.

Let me know if you need me to clarify.

Comment: I guess value1 should be put inside single quotes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second option (generating the scripts) seems like the best one.

Now, as for your error.  Is your agency code a string?  Then that is probably the problem:  you need to enclose it in quotation marks.  Since you are building a string, they will need to be doubled:

```
 select 'update dbo.' + t.TABLE_NAME + 
        ' set agency = ''value1a'' where agency = ''value1'''
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
  join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1
    on T.TABLE_NAME = C1.TABLE_NAME
  join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2
    on t.TABLE_NAME = c2.TABLE_NAME
  where t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    and c1.COLUMN_NAME = 'agency'
    and c2.COLUMN_NAME = 'agency'
```

Your example had you setting agency to `'value1'` when it was previously `'value1a'`, but from your description of the requirements it sounds like it should be the other way around.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Everyone reminded me of the double quote requirement, but I appreciate the extra information you provided on why I was messing up.  I can share this script example with my co-workers now as we have similar situations that come up like this.

Answer (score 0):

`value1` and `value1a` are a string values so they need to be enclosed in quotes, otherwise your script is considering them to be column names, as specified in the error.

So try:

```
select 'update dbo.' + t.TABLE_NAME + 
       ' set agency = ''value1'' where agency = ''value1a'''
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!  Seems I was forgetting the double quote requirement.  That corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your script escaping the values with double quotes:

```
    select 'update dbo.' + t.TABLE_NAME + ' set agency = ''value1'' where agency = ''value1a'' '
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1
on T.TABLE_NAME = C1.TABLE_NAME
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2
on t.TABLE_NAME = c2.TABLE_NAME
where t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
and c1.COLUMN_NAME = 'agency'
and c2.COLUMN_NAME = 'agency'
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!  Seems I was forgetting the double quote requirement.  That corrected it.